# How to set prefix kolom in SQL/MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysqli

I Have query example like this:

```
select * from mytable;
```

Result Normal Like this :

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
```

SO How to add prefix column in my table and get like this:

```
|myprefix_col1|myprefix_col2|myprefix_col3|
```

UPDATE:

```
Select a.*, b.* from tbl1 a inner join tbl2 b on a.id = b.idA
```

How to add prefix in all kolom `b.* prefix`

thanks,

hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use alias

```
select 
col1 as myprefix_col1,
col2 as myprefix_col2,
col3 as myprefix_col3
 from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your prefix to your query,

If you want the prefix with the data the you can use following query.

```
select prefix_||col1,prefix_||col2,prefix_||col3 from yourtable
```

If you just want to add prefix to your column name then you can use alias,

```
select col1 as perfix_col1, col2 as prefix_col2, col3 as prefix_col3 from yourtable;
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: hmm exactualy i know if initial use "AS", but i don't want to initial my column one by one <br> i want to do like this "select "prefix_here" a.* from mytable a"  thanks